# Is it bad practice to init class members with list of obj in ctor?

Tags: c#, oop, constructor, factory-pattern

```
ClassName(List<object> obj) : base(obj[0])
{
   member1 = obj[1];
   ...
}
```

I have an assignment in oop C# . Ive implemented a factory design pattern and the class i'm initializing is determined in runtime. Furthermore the obj list is changing due to user inputs. Is it bad or best practice to init class members this way more than the classic way of getting all specific params at ctor like :

```
ClassName(int a, float b, ClassName2 c)
```

Comment: The above is not valid `C#` syntax. This is now how constructors are defined. Please [edit] the post and correct the syntax.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou The syntax itself is perfectly valid.

Comment: @TanveerBadar - it is missing the class declaration. It is only valid under a lot of assumptions here. Also the above is a **constructor** and not a factory pattern.

Comment: @TanveerBadar i've shown an example that is nessecary for the que, this isn't part of my code neither the factory design pattern..Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

For the code provided: yes.

I would say even more it is not a bad practice nor an opinion: here it is a fault.

Because if the list is empty, or null, you will get an exception.

You have to check bounds in the constructor and do things differently.

For example:

```
class BaseClass
{
  protected void Initialize(object instance)
  {
    ...
  }
  public BaseClass(object instance)
  {
    Initialize(instance);
  }
}

class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
  ChildClass(List<object> items)
  {
    if ( items.Count > 0 ) Initialize(items[0]);
    if ( items.Count > 1 ) member1 = items[1];
    ...
  }
}
```

Perhaps you can use a collection (array, list...) of properties and a loop on this mapping table.

Of course, you can also write such a thing:

```
ChildClass(List<object> items) : base(items != null && items.Count > 0 ? items[0] : null)
```

But in principle and without knowing more code and specifications, the `null` bothers me a little, unless it is well managed and therefore everything will be fine... a default value may be used, but this is the role of the base class, not the child, unless it must be changed.

Comment: thanks! after reading your answer I now realize that in this case - "Clean code" (ctor at Child doesn't get 10 params) is good but enters more option for bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean implementing a constructor with `List<object>` as a single argument in lieu of multiple arguments for each property.

Since c# is *type safe* it is not recommended to do this. Not only casting from various types to `object` and back again is dangerous, it is also slow and can introduce subtle bugs that are hard to find.

### The recommended way

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected BaseClass(string baseName)
    {
        this.BaseName=baseName;
    }

    public string BaseName { get; }    
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass(string baseName, int iD) 
        : base(baseName)
    {
        this.ID=iD;
    }

    public int ID { get; }
}
```

### The not so recommended ways

using `params object[]`

```
    public DerivedClass(params object[] args)
        : base( args[0] as string)
    {
        this.ID = (int)args[1];
    }
```

using `List<object>`

```
    public DerivedClass(List<object> args)
        : base( args[0] as string)
    {
        this.ID = (int)args[1];
    }
```

### Alternative type safe way

You can also use a `ValueTuple` to carry the arguments

```
    public DerivedClass((string baseName, int id) args)
        : base( args.baseName)
    {
        this.ID = args.id;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I realize that my will for clean code open a door for other bugs and issues so perhaps i'll stay with your "The Recommended Way"!